# Program ends after user input

Tags: c, input, user-input

Program that I wrote stops after user input, and I don't have any idea why this is happening. User should give 6 integers, and after that program should do some math with it which isn't the case right now, because after inserting integers it ends, with no error.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>


 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int T,i;
    int x[5];

     scanf("%d", &T);
     while(T > 0) {
         for(i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
             scanf("%d", &x[i]);
          }
          int size_tax = x[0] + x[1] + x[2];
          int tax[size_tax];

          for(i = 0; i <= size_tax; i++) {
              if(i == 0) {
                   tax[i] = x[0];
                   if(x[4] == 1) {
                       printf("%d", tax[0]);
                       break;
                    } 
              } else if(i > 0 && i <= x[1] - 1) {
                  tax[i] = tax[i-1] + 1;
                  if(x[4] == i + 1) {
                      printf("%d", tax[i]);
                      break;
                   }
              } else if(i > x[1] - 1 && i <= x[2] - 1) {
                  tax[i] = tax[i-1] * 2;
                      if(x[4] == i + 1) {
                      printf("%d", tax[i]);
                      break;
                    }
              }
          }

         if(x[4] > x[0] + x[1] + x[2]) {
              int result = x[3] - 1;
              for(i = x[3]; i <= x[4] - 1; i++) {
                  result = result * x[i];

              }

              printf("%d", result);
        }

         T--;
      }
 }
```

Comment: which user input? before the while loop?

Comment: you've got two scanf() calls. which one is causing the problem?

Comment: `int tax[size_tax]` is not valid. you cannot initialize an array like that. size_tax is dynamically determined at runtime and is not available at compile-time. You need to malloc() some memory first...

Comment: @MarcB: C has variable length arrays.

Comment: If you use a debugger the program is working fine. Are your inputs matching one of the print statements? If you 1 all six times it will print out 1.

Comment: @marc: Yes, as of the last millennium ;)

Comment: _give 6 integers_ `5`.

Comment: You might like to compile the code with symbols (option `-g` for gcc) and run the program using a debugger (gdb). Doing so you can trace through the code inspecting all relevant variables. This way you see what **really** happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
int tax[size_tax];

for(i = 0; i <= size_tax; i++) {
     ...
}
```

The declared size of `tax` is `size_tax`, so the loop must go up to `size_tax-1`, so it should be

```
for(i = 0; i < size_tax; i++) { // Less than, not less than or equal to
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input your testing is 1 2 3 4 5 6 then that's perfectly normal. Just insert an else after the last else if. 
It seems this input won't verify any other condition.